# abstract base class with async methods that can sometimes be sync

Tags: javascript

tl;dr - how to make a version of a class that has all its async methods replace by sync ones? (or visa versa)

Background info:

I have created an abstract base class using symbols, something like this:

```
  const sProtectedMethod = Symbol();
  class AbstractBase() {
    constructor() {
      if (new.target === AbstractBase) {
        throw new TypeError(`AbstractBase is abstract and cannot be instantiated directly. Use a derived class`);
      }
    }
    async #protectedMethod() { // this is just a convience to avoid the ugly symbol syntax everytime we call the function
      await this[sProtectedMethod]();
    }
    async publicMethod() {
      await longAndComplexFunctionCallChainThatEventuallyAwaitsProtectedMethodButDoesntAwaitAnythingElse();

  }
```

where the derived classes look like this:

```
  class Derived extends AbstractBase {
    async [sProtectedMethod]() {
      // implementation here
    }
```

So far so good. But - in some derived classes the implementation of the overriden method must be async (because it does I/O or whatever) while in other implementations this method *could* be synchronus.
I did an experiment to see if making the method synchronus would be faster and it is - approx. 1000x faster.

I could make 2 versions of the AbstractBase - a sync and an async version. But here's the catch - the protectedMethod is actually called many times, pretty deep into a long chain of functions - all of which must be async if the overriden implementation is also async.

So rather than maintain 2 versions of the class that are almost identical, I'd like a way to automatically create a sync version from an async version, or visa versa.

I have managed this with a string replace and an eval

```
const AbstractBaseSync = eval(`${AbstractBase.toString().replace(/async|await/g, ``)}; AbstractBase`);
```

But even though I *think* this is safe (providing there are no strings within the class that contain the words async or await), the use of eval and I'm hoping there is a better way.

Also, although it seems to work in Chrome, Firefox + Node - I know implementations of `toString` may differ, which might cause issues later.

If I dispensed with the #private members and used _convention instead, then maybe I could do it member by member with reflection, but I don't think it would be much better as `eval` or `new Function(...)` would still be required.

What is the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: While checking over the question I have realised that I could move the string replace part to a compile-time thing and just emit a 2nd file with the Sync version in it.

That way there is no `eval`. But we still have the string manipulation, so I'm still not entirely happy with that approach and better solutions are welcome.